# Change color of dates on monthCalendar

Tags: c#, monthcalendar

How do I change the color of the dates on a monthCalendar? I have a dataGridView with a column for dates. How do I takes those dates, input them into my monthCalendar, and change the color of the dates in the column?

Comment: I need a bit of clarification. Do you want to change the colors the MonthCalendar uses? Or do you want to change the color of the date in the DataGridView?  Or both?

Comment: I want to change the color of the date in the monthCalendar. I don't wan to change the entire monthCalendar look, just the bolded dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get away with bolding the dates, just use AddAnnuallyBoldedDate and then call UpdateBoldedDates.

**Update:**  [Found this on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/MPK_Calendar.aspx).

Comment: a pity that this does not inherit from MonthCalandar... That can be used with multiple months at a time....